# Library import structure in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am developing a library in python3x and I'm having some trouble trying to import all modules, classes and functions.

```
    /example.py
    /math/
        __init__.py
        linalg.py
             solve() #inside module.py
```

The issue here is that I would like to simply be able to import my library  inside example.py and then use all functions defined inside the different modules as numpy does, for example:

```
import math as m

m.solve()
```

instead of using

```
import math as m
m.linalg.solve()
```

or

```
import math.linalg as m
m.solve()
```

How should I define __init__.py to include everything this way. I've tried using dir(linalg), absolute imports, etc by I can't get my head around it.

Thx.

**SOLUTION**:

At the end what I did was create a wrapping layer inbetween to hide the module dependency.

Inside the __init__.py:

```
from .linalg import *
from .wrappers import *
```

then created a wrappers.py along with linalg.py:

```
from math.linalg import solve

def wrapper_solver():
{
solve()
}
```

and then in example.py:

```
import math as m

m.wrapper_solver()
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions :

1. **Either import the whole path to your linalg.py :**

`example.py` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                         

import math.linalg as m # rather than just `import math`.

m.solve()
```

2. **Either make solve available directly from math with your __init__.py** :

`math/__init__.py` :

```
from linalg import solve
```

---

*Edit :*

You could modify your python path as Muhammed Ajwahir suggested. But in my humble opinion that doesn't solve the problem. It's a matter of import path. The root directory is added by default to the Python path (when executing `./example.py`). That's enough to import everything in sub directories. I think there is no need to modify the path.

*Edit 2:*

If you want to import everything in your `__init__.py` you can also use `from math import *` (which is considered as a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386740/3156085)). Or add everything by hand in your `__init__.py`.

But in your case you might consider refactoring your tree in just :

```
.
|-- example.py
|-- math.py
```

And forget the `math` directory structure. This way a simple `import math` should be enough.

I'd also like to point out that `math` is already an existing library in Python. I think you should consider renaming it to avoid name conflict.

Comment: Yes, I have tried both and I'm leaning towards the second but the list of functions in the \__init__.py would be huge

Comment: The problem is that I'd like to call the library from several files and putting them all wouldn't be possible, and adding them all by hand doesn't seem like a good practice either (that's why I mentioned the dir() command to try to do it automatically). Also the names are made up ^^

Comment: @GabrielEsp I think the best solution is still to import things explicitly in your `__init__.py`. Maybe you don't need to import everything but only the most used functions and functions you need outside o your math package.

For most common functions -> import in `__init__.py`. For any other function/class/item, use the full path in your python import.

Answer (score 0):

In your linalg.py write  `__ all __`  write all the function you want to expose to the package.
example  `__ all __ =['solve']`

Then in `__ init __.py` ( module where linalg.py file is present ) file write `from .linalg import *` this will import all function defined in `__ all __` 
 (note function name should be unique) .
and then in `__ init __.py` write  `__ all __ = linalg.__ all __` ( use `+` if there are more file ie `__ all __ = linalg.__ all __ +file2.__ all __` .

and then in the example, you can call `solve` as `from math import solve`.

Comment: @GabrielEsp solution updated. please note __ all __   has no space.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add something inside a folder you have to add that folder in the system directory. you can do that by -

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/math/folder')

import linalg as m

m.solve()
```

**EDIT 1:**

OR

In __init__.py,
add

```
__all__ = ["linalg", "foo", "barr"]
```

etc, and `import math as m` in your main script
hope that helps.

Comment: No, but I want to import the whole package. Imagine I have not only linalg, but several other modules. The goal would be to import the whole package and call all functions from the package import.

Comment: In that case in your init.py you have to add -  ` __all __ = ["linalg", "foo", "barr"]
` etc, and  ` import math as m ` in your main script.

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem.
It's a matter of import path. The root directory is added by default to the Python path (when executing `./example.py`). That's enough to import everything in subdirectories. I think there is no need to modify the path.

Comment: I have done that but I get AttributeError: module 'math' has not attribute 'linalg'

Comment: How did you access the function ? If you import math as m, then you access the function name func() inside the linalg as m.linalg.func()

Comment: Yes, but in the description of the problem I explain that my goal is to access the function only using m.func()